# Use a modified XPages Theme for IBM Connections?

Tags: css, xpages, ibm-connections, ibm-oneui

The XPages applications built use a Theme that is based on IBM OneUI but alters it in some parts. Now that look and feel should be used for IBM Connections which also is based on IBM OneUI. How to port the changes?

Comment: Tags should be IBM-OneUI and IBM-Connections but I don't have enough repudiation yet

Comment: Is this primarily a question for IBM Connections and how to modify OneUI there? I'm just trying to understand the issue

Comment: Stephen what exactly is your question? It's not clear.

Comment: This is more of an admin question and probably should be asked on Serverfault.com

Comment: I have a working modified OneUI Theme in Domino. Now I need to apply that changes to a IBM COnnections installation. Is there an easy way to keep that in sync. YES --> mostly a connections question (for the seeding part, for harvesting it would be Domino)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract your modifications into a new css file. If that stylesheet is loaded after the OneUI styles the will be applied according to the rules of css specificity (if rules have the same specificity then the last one declared wins: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade).

This will allow you you to use the same style sheet for Domino apps, Connections and anything else that uses OneUI.